# Getting Facebook Group Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the below error when using php curl to get a Facebook group feed.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
             [message] => Invalid OAuth access token signature.
             [type] => OAuthException
             [code] => 190
        )

)
```

This is what I've done so far.

- Created an app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- Get an access token using curl: https:// graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

Is the client_id the same as the "App ID/API Key" that you get when creating a new Facebook app? If not, where do I find the client_ID?

- Get the group feed using curl: https:// graph.facebook.com/440783062666183/feed?access_token=$accessToken

The API replies with the above error message, how do I get a valid OAuth access token?

I can get the feed using the "Graph API Explorer", just struggling to find the correct access token!

---

Ok this what I've managed to find out since writing the above.

If I use the Facebook Graph API Explorer to get the access token and select user_groups.

Then hardcode this into my php script I can get the feed !!

How do I get this access token using php curl ??

This returns the group feed that I need https:// graph.facebook.com/440783062666183/feed?access_token=$accessToken -- Note that $accessToken is hardcoded with an access token generated from the Graph API Explorer.

How do I get the correct access token ??